# Can I install a soil drainage system near the grade surface?

Tags: drain

Recently, due to either geologic movement or erosion, my home has developed a few "bathtubs" around the foundation where water tends to roll toward the house. I'm curious to add a perimeter drain to whisk this water away. Researching this, you typically see drains placed near the footing for new construction. But since my issue has to do with water in the topsoil, **is it possible to excavate only a few feet down and follow the same general process, i.e. landscape fabric, perf pipe, 1/4" stone, grade slightly away from the home**?

In general, I also don't understand: **how does water accumulate into and drain away within the perforated pipe**? If the fabric were replaced with *nonpermeable* plastic, I see how a significant amount might accumulate inside the plastic, then drain into the pipe. But the fabric is permeable anyway.

Is there another drainage type option to consider? Gutters are in good shape. Note I can't build up the soil grade because it's already very close to the rimjoist and I want a good 6"-10" of concrete foundation to keep insects out.

Comment: How does perf pipe work: Water takes the route of least resistance. As it's soaking through the dirt, it finds the fabric which wicks it away from the dirt. All of a sudden, there's air on the other side (the inside of the pipe) which has very low resistance to flow, so the water moves in that direction and it's now in the pipe. Once it's in the pipe, it wants to stay there because there's less resistance to staying in the pipe than there is to soaking out through the fabric and into the soil. Of course, some will, but the vast majority won't.

Comment: @FreeMan, why isn't that an answer?

Comment: Because, @isherwood, it struck me as being a tangential question to the title question and the main question asked in the body. This is one of the reasons SE has a "one question per question" rule.

Comment: It gets to the crux of the primary question as well.

Answer (score 2):

The French drain relies on the water table meeting the level of the drain, if the water table is below the drain no water flows.

When there is surface water that is the level of the water table.

Answer (score 1):

To add a bit of clarity to Jasen's correct but brief answer...

- Drain tile (a legacy term for what's now commonly sleeved, perforated, corrugated plastic pipe) can be installed at any height, as the situation warrants. I've used it at footing level 10 feet down, in arched configuration under windows, and near grade level. It's just a path for gravity flow, after all.
- Water percolates out of the soil and into the system. There it flows freely to a downstream outlet, either daylighted or at a sump. This works because water can drain more readily there than in the surrounding soil.
- The fact that some water percolates back *out* of the drain tile is usually immaterial. The soil around is typically saturated anyway if there's water in the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

> how does water accumulate into and drain away within the perforated pipe

Water always takes the route of least resistance.

As it's soaking through the dirt, it finds the fabric which wicks it away from the dirt. All of a sudden, there's air on the other side (the inside of the pipe) which has very low resistance to flow, so the water moves in that direction and it's now in the pipe. Once it's in the pipe, it wants to stay there because there's less resistance to staying in the pipe than there is to soaking out through the fabric and into the soil. Of course, some will, but the vast majority won't.

Additionally, when the soil is saturated, there is a small amount of water pressure in the soil, pushing the water around. The open area inside the pipe is basically zero resistance to the movement of water, so it will flow into the pipe very easily. Since there is a small amount of pressure outside the pipe, that pressure will work to keep the water in the pipe.